# When is better to use preload or eager_load or includes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

|  | SQL contains join | Load associated record in memory | Performs two queries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| preload | no | yes | yes |
| includes | yes (left outer join) | yes | sometimes |
| eager load | (left outer join) | yes | no |

I am aware from the concepts.

I want to know when to use which API. I search but does not find exact answer.

Comment: Rails Guides was [just updated to explain this](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ba3933c4db1696ea2badedb2455bc3329216eabc), but it hasn't made it into a release yet. You can read the [updated Eager Loading Associations guide](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6f519dc9440b883f1d88af5ae01ec84dc11aeafc/guides/source/active_record_querying.md#eager-loading-associations) on Github. However, I'm still left scratching my head.

Comment: Right @Schwern. That still does not clarified in which conditions to use preload and eager_load.

Comment: I would say this question is off-topic. The answer to this question would require an entire article and its hard to answer the "better" part without delving into opinion. It also depends entirely upon the context - ie what you're going to do with the data and what conditions you're applying to the query.

Answer (score 8):

`includes` chooses whether to use `preload` or `eager_load`. If you're not happy with the decision `includes` makes, you have to resort to using either of `eager_load` or `preload`

---

From https://engineering.gusto.com/a-visual-guide-to-using-includes-in-rails/:

**When does :includes use :preload?**

In most cases :includes will default to use the method :preload which will fire 2 queries:

- Load all records tied to the leading model
- Load records associated with the leading model based off the foreign key on the associated model or the leading model

**When does :includes use :eager_load?**

:includes will default to use :preload unless you reference the association being loaded in a subsequent clause, such as :where or :order. When constructing a query this way, you also need to explicitly reference the eager loaded model.

```rb
Employee.includes(:forms).where('forms.kind = "health"').references(:forms)
```

Answer (score 1):

all these methods help to stay away from N+1 query problem, the key difference is between them how you want to query:

1. preload: 2 sql queries
2. includes: if it is a simple query, then 2 sql query; else left join in used
3. eager_load: left join
   all of these loads and stores data in memory temporarily.